# Javascript Function returning 'NaN' or 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have following code :

```
    getLastInsertId = function(collection, field){

    field = (typeof field === "undefined") ? '_id' : field;


    var qry = JSON.parse('{"fields" :{"'+field+'": 1}, "sort" : {"$natural": -1}, "limit": 1}');
    //console.log(qry);
    var lastInsertId = collection.find({}, qry).fetch()[0];

    if(lastInsertId === 'undefined'){
        //var x = 1;
        return "1";
        //console.log(Number(1));


    }else{
        //return (+lastInsertId + 1);

    }



};
```

If I use following, it returns NaN:

```
return 1;
```

Can some one guide me, what I am doing wrong and how it can be rectified.

Comment: if (typeof  lastInsertId=== "undefined") {

}  use this

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var qry = {"fields" :{"'+field+'": 1}, "sort" : {"$natural": -1}, "limit": 1};
//console.log(qry);
var lastInsertId = collection.findOne(qry);
lastInsertId = lastInsertId._id;
```